# Javascript writing into Table not working

Tags: javascript, html, class, html-table, innerhtml

I just decided to code a little html file which should create a multiplication table with integers from "start" to "end". Start and End are set before in a HTMl Form...

I can give 2 numbers as input and the tr and td elements are create but accessing them by ClassName and filling them with innerHTML does somehow not work.
Here is the Code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Das groࠥ 1x1</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function malnehmen(Wert1, Wert2) {
        Ausgabe = Wert1 * Wert2;
        return Ausgabe;
    }
    function tabelle() {
        var start = document.forms["printer"].anfang.value;
        var end = document.forms["printer"].ende.value;
        for(i = start; i < end+1; i++) {
            Reihe = document.createElement("tr");
            att = document.createAttribute("class");
            att.value = i + "a";
            Reihe.setAttributeNode(att);
            document.getElementById("Darein").appendChild(Reihe);
            for(ii = start; ii < end+1; ii++) {
                Feld = document.createElement("td");
                att2 = document.createAttribute("class");
                att2.value = malnehmen(i, ii);
                Feld.setAttributeNode(att2);
                Reihe.appendChild(Feld);
            }
        }
    }
    function ausfuellen() {
        tabelle();
        var start = document.forms["printer"].anfang.value;
        var end = document.forms["printer"].ende.value;
        for(a = start; a < end+1; a++) {
            alert("Hier denn?");
            document.getElementsByClassName(a + "a").innerHTML = a.toString();
            for(aa = start; aa < end+1; aa++) {
                multi = malnehmen(a, aa);
                alert("Angekommen");
                document.getElementsByClassName(multi).innerHTML = multi.toString();
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<body>
    <FORM name="printer">
        <TABLE>
            <tr>
                <td>Beginnt bei:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" name="anfang" size="3">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Endet bei:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" name="ende" size="3">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" name="wassolldas" value="Erstellen" onclick="javascript: tabelle();">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </TABLE>
    </FORM>
    <br>
    <TABLE id="Darein" border="1">
    </TABLE>
</body>
```

Does anybody know what I did wrong?
I built in 2 alerts just to see if the javascript part reaches the for loop but there is no pop up in browser.

Comment: try putting the script within the `<head></head>` section

Comment: You're never running the function `ausfuellen` so I'm not sure why you would expect the alerts to come up. when is that supposed to run?

Comment: @pabs123 oh thank you! So simple i just didnt look for that. The Button started the right function first but then I changed it because browser said the function was not found. I forgot to change it again. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Okay i fixed it now! But it still does not access the <td> elements by their class!

Comment: `function reechner() {`
`for(a = start; a < end+1; a++) {`
`Inhalt = document.createTextNode(a);`
`Erstes = document.getElementsByClassName(a + "a").firstChild;`
`Erstes.appendChild(Inhalt);`
`for(aa = start; aa < end+1; aa++) {`
`multi = malnehmen(a, aa);`
`document.getElementsByClassName(multi).innerHTML = "<p>" + multi + "</p>";`
`}`
`}`
`}`


Both ways to edit the content of the td elements do not work!